# Short notation for coffeescript try/catch

Tags: syntax, coffeescript, try-catch, shortcut

I sometimes write code like:

```
try doSomething()
catch e
  handleError e
```

which is not what nice and clean coffeescript code should look like.

Is there a way to write:

```
try doSomething()
catch e handleError e   #<-- will not compile
```

This would save me about 33% of the lines of code in my try/catch statements ;)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Writing try/catch one-liners works like if-then one-liners or loop one-liners using the `then` keyword:

```
try doSomething()
catch e then handleError e
finally cleanUp()
```

You can even have it on a single line if you like:

```
try doSomething() catch e then handleError e finally cleanUp()
```

Comment: Also, the `then` is optional, and no `;`'s are required when you put them all together. So this is valid too: `try doSomething() catch e then handleError e finally cleanUp()`

Comment: When having `catch e` and `handle e` in one line you still need the `then` otherwise it does not compile: http://coffeescript.org/#try:try%20doSomething%28%29%0Acatch%20e%20handleError%20e%0Afinally%20cleanUp%28%29

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear, I meant 'the `then`-*clause* is optional. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Catching errors without then-clause is also quite useful when handling errors asynchronously. In that case, you usually do not want to callback within the try or catch block, but afterwards: `try result = a() catch e; if e? then cb e else cb null, result` This is possible, since the coffee-script (other than vanilla JS) automatically extracts the error variable from the catch scope.

Answer (score 3):

Cross-posting from https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/issues/2413:

FWIW, I discovered you can write

```
try
   compute something
catch error
    handle error 
unless error?
    handle success
```

This is possible since CS puts the variable of the `catch` clause into the surrounding scope, which JS does not do. One might even argue that saying `unless error?` is clearer than both `else` (this is not an `if` clause) and `continue` (this is not a loop) in that position.

People who insist on oneliners can even write

```
try compute something catch error then handle error unless error? then handle success
```

which is somewhat cool and somewhat unreadable.

A `finally` clause would have to go *before* the `unless`, of course.